# ASP.NET Javascript: window.open won't work twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, hidden, window.open

I have an aspx page with a button. When the user clicks that button, the following javascript opens a new browser window (in this case, 'Reasons.aspx'). Works great. Here's the function for that part:

```
function ShowPanel(url)
{
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
params += ', toolbar=no';
params += ', menubar=no';
params += ', resizable=yes';
params += ', directories=no';
params += ', scrollbars=no';
params += ', status=no';
params += ', location=no';
newwin = window.open(url + '?LetterNumber=1&ReasonType=3', 'd', params); //<--- Change This (LetterNumber) When Copying!
if (window.focus) 
    {
    newwin.focus() 
    }
return false;
}
```

Now here's where it gets funky. When this window pops up, there are some controls. One of which is a button, which triggers almost identical code to popup a third window (in this case, ReasonCodes.aspx). Only it won't work. Here's the code for that:

```
function fGetReasons(url)
{
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
params += ', toolbar=no';
params += ', menubar=no';
params += ', resizable=yes';
params += ', directories=no';
params += ', scrollbars=no';
params += ', status=no';
params += ', location=no';
newwin = window.open(url, 'd', params); //<--- Change This (LetterNumber) When Copying!
if (window.focus) 
    {
    newwin.focus() 
    }
return false;
}
```

I've set breakpoints on the javascript. It does execute. Here's what's weird -- The above javascript executes, only I don't get a new window with ReasonCodes.aspx. However, I set a breakpoint in the page_load of ReasonCodes.aspx and all of it executes. So the javascript executes, the code-behind page_load of the third page executes, but I don't get a third page.

Instead, the second window (Reasons.aspx) refreshes. It's like my third window is somehow 'hidden'.

Can anybody tell me what's going on, or what am I missing?

Thanks,

Jason

PS -- I know 3 windows sounds like a lot, and it's not by choice. There's a business need here (this is a local intranet application) and I have to abide by the specs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to `window.open` is the name of the window.  You are using the same name in both calls so it is attempting to use the same window.  Change the name of the 2nd call and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Or use '_blank' name to open each time in new window!